# OSM2PO Routing - reroute when traffic jam

Tags: osm2po

is possible to force osm2po to reroute when traffic jam or other problem is detected on the route ? Or is it possible to tell osm2po routing to avoid some node/way even when it is best route ?

I'm not Java programmer so I prefer non Java solution

Comment: What do you mean? pgRouting or osm2po-REST (http/geojson) ? ... and no, there is currently no default handling for this. You need Java Skills in order to modify the routing behavior to your needs.

Comment: Any updates on your problem?

Comment: no, not yet, it look like i have to learn java to be able to affect routing .. or to use different routing engine which i do not want - i like osm2po, for me it's fast and easy to use ...

Answer (score 1):

Both methods outlined below provide solutions from a transportation rather than a computer science based approach.

**Method 1**

The way this is done properly in [Travel Demand Modelling (TDM)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transportation_forecasting) is in the [Trip Assignment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Route_assignment) stage of the model.

Using the FHWA model, you can do the following:

- In your layer, create a new column for each time period you're modelling for:

  - A new field called `Volume`
  - A new field called `Time_to_traverse`
  - Create a new column for each time period you're modelling and let's call it capacity
- You either have to compute Volume of Traffic using Trip Distribution models or existing traffic feeds
- Capacity as as a start could be assumed as `1600` passenger vehicles per lane per hour.
- `V/C` = Volume over capacity tells you how full the highway is

Use the following equation to estimate the Time to traverse the link:

`Ti = T_o [1 + 0.15*(V/C)^4]`

Where:

- T_i = Balanced (iterative approach)
- T_o = free flow travel time
- V = assigned volume for that link
- C = practical capacity

**Now that you have your Volume, Capacity, and Time to traverse fields for your time periods, you can set up your model to traverse using `cost=time_to_traverse` rather than `cost=link_length`. when V/C approaches one, `time_to_traverse` will go up and the model will reroute accordingly**

**Method 2:**

- Create two field in your layer: `Virtual_length`, and `virtual_factor`
- If you know when volumes or traffic jams are going to occur on certain roads, assign those roads a `Virtual factor` and `Virtual_length = Virtual_factor * real_length`
- Route based on Virtual_length

**Final Note:**

I think this is a traffic engineering and modelling exercise more so than a programming problem

Comment: Your solution is too sophisticated for data i can use ... I have just information that on some road is traffic level 5 which mean complete stuck and i want to recalculate navigation route to avoid this place/node.

I know this is complicated problem but i want to do simple even not so perfect solution ( informations what is traffic jam and what is jam level is not from me ... )

Comment: In the case where they have a level of service, indicated by numbers assuming 1 to 5. I assume 1 is free flow, 4 is equilibrium and 5 is failure. you can use those as your fudge factor? or can you deduce some fudge factors from them and try to apply method 2?

Comment: when you speaking about layer, you mean layer in osm2po ? I'm i able to change database data in routing engine ? I'm sorry if it is dump question but i'm using osm2po as routing engine with json, and i was never digging inside it to see how it work or what else it can do. thanks